# unix c-shell : disk checking

Tags: disk, csh

im totally new in shell scripting. I have task to simplify an old c shell script. Basically, the script have 10 devices that using hp-ux and i want to check the disk space in each devices. my requirement is if the space more than 90%, the info of device and space will be save to a log. this is list of device and ip address which i set as variable ipadd:

```
lo1 100.45.32.43
lot2 100.45.32.44
lot3 100.45.32.44
lot4 100.45.32.45
lot5 100.45.32.46 
and so on.
```

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set ipaddress = (`awk '{print $2}' "ipadd"`)
set device = (`awk '{print $1}' "ipadd"`)
@ j = 1
set i = 90
while($j <= $#ipaddress)
set space = (`rsh $ipaddress[$j]  bdf | grep /dev/vg00|awk '{print $5}' |   cut -c 1-2`)
echo $space[$j]

set file =(`rsh $ipaddress[$j]  bdf | grep /dev/vg00 |awk '{print $6}'`)
echo $file

if ( {$space[$j]} >= {$i} ) then
echo "hi"
echo "$device[$j]/$file[$j] has reached $space[$j] . Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." >> /script/dev.file

endif

@ j++
end
```

the output for bdf:

```
/dev/vg00/lvol2    15300207 10924582 28566314   79% /
/dev/vg00/lvol4      42529   23786   25510   55% /stand
```

Output after exec in .file:

```
lot1// has reached 79 . Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY...
lot2//stand has reached 56 . Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY...
```

My question is:

why the output only for /dev/vg00/lvol2  for each device and not for /dev/vg00/lvol4?

thanks.

Comment: Your script is only dealing with the first line of the bdf output.

Comment: how to dealing with the second output?

Comment: I would probably send the outout through `read`, but not sure in csh - I use bash normally.